# SSRS , 2 datasets with a common Key ID using a List and Table

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-grouping

I want to have a List of a specific entity with 2 table in it using 2 differents DataSet.

Is there any way to embed 2 table in a list? It seem to not be possible.

```
DataSet 1 
  LocationID (PKEY)
  Name 
  Address

DataSet 2 
  LocationID (PKEY)
  Employee

DataSet 3 
  LocationID (PKEY)
  Sales
```

> Here is Waht I wanted to do

```
List with DataSet 1 (LocationID as my Reference Key)<br/>
  Table With DataSet 2 (LocationID as my Reference Key)<br/>
  Table With DataSet 3 (LocationID as my Reference Key)
```

Comment: You can make a subreport with the tables 2 & 3 in it, and put the subreport in the list item, and pass the LocationID from DataSet1 to the subreport.

Comment: Is there a way to do it other than using a subreport since I will have at least 10 tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No directly you can not use two `datasets` on same `List` or for that matter on `Tablix` or `Matrix` control. But there are 2 ways to do what you want to do.

1) As  @ Tab Alleman suggested you can use the `subreport` for other tables and include it in your list

2) If you have the `Reference Key` in each of your `dataset` then you can use the `LookUp` [Here is more info.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee210531.aspx)

But using `LookUp` can get very complicated and I would suggest you to use the `SubReport`.

Comment: I don't think so (Not sure !) , Because the way I see it the dataset is going to execute the query in both cases one time only thing that can cause the performance issue in subreport is rendering the other report as subreport. That is also don't take that much of time. If you want you can go with both approaches for 2 tables and measure the performance issues if there are any.